# How to structure image paths in ascidoctor?

Tags: asciidoc, asciidoctor

I have a book with the following directory structure

```
book.adoc
chapters/chapter1.adoc
chapters/chapter2.adoc
chapters/chapter3.adoc
images/img1.jpg
images/img2.jpg
```

in `book.adoc` I include the chapters. The problem is that in each chapter I include images from the images directory. If I use a path relative to `book.adoc` then the images render when I generate the PDF of the entire book, but not when I generate a PDF of an individual chapter.

This is particularly annoying when working on a chapter and the HTML preview does not show the images.

Is there a way to specify the paths so it works in both cases? Is the only way to move the chapters up a directory?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Your documents can specify the `imagesdir` attribute. See [the documentation](https://docs.asciidoctor.org/asciidoc/latest/macros/images-directory/#imagesdir-attribute-syntax).

If you specify `imagesdir` as a relative path, such as `./images`, then you can have chapter-specific image folders that should allow your full and chapter-specific builds to work, as well as make the HTML preview work.